# Set App language permanently

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, app-store

I have an app localized in 2 languages, I want to set it to second language and send it to App Store so it shows that language regardless of user device language selection.
I know about command line argument, AppleLanguages, but I want to change the language in compiled app, including Launch Image and Icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this language manager:https://github.com/antrix1989/LanguageManager
It allows change language in runtime regardless of user device language. You can achive your goal by hardcoding the language identifier for each build.

**EDIT**

As far as I understood, you can not change Launch image and icon programmatically...

- [Dynamically change launch image in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015532/dynamically-change-launch-image-in-ios)
- [Can I change app icon programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042275/can-i-change-app-icon-programmatically)

Comment: But this does not support Launch Image and Icon

Comment: @AVEbrahimi as far as I understood, it is not possible.